Spotify API will not return relavant playlist
Beginner here, working on a project in make.com to generate playlists automatically from my likes.
I want my genre to correspond directly to "The Sounds of Spotify" but I am running into trouble trying to return the playlist I need.
I know the exact playlist I am looking for "The Sound of [Genre]" and I know the user "The Sounds of Spotify".
But Spotify API returns garbage playlists all the time, when Desktop and Web App return the correct playlist every time with the same search terms.
Please forgive any mistakes as I attempt to render make.com into URL:
I have tried (using the Spotify - Make an API Call module):
/v1/search?q=the+sound+of+[genre]&type=playlist&offset=0&limit=1
/v1/search?q=the+sound+of+[genre]&type=playlist&offset=0&limit=1&market=US
/v1/users/thesoundsofspotify/playlists?q="the+sound+of+[genre]&limit=1&offset=0
I have tried dozens of parmutations of the above with no luck.
It sort of works, 50% of the time I get the right playlist - the rest of the time "indie rock" returns "Christian Alternative 2024" or something equally off-base and unrelated to my search.
Even though "The Sound of Indie Rock" clearly exists in the user "The Sounds of Spotify"
Here is an example input bundle:
[
    {
        "qs": [
            {
                "key": "q",
                "value": "\"the+sound+of+indie rock\""
            },
            {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "playlist"
            },
            {
                "key": "offset",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "key": "limit",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "key": "market",
                "value": "US"
            }
        ],
        "url": "/v1/search?",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Thanks for any help you can lend!
